# Is it possible to read a CLOB from a remote Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386172/why-is-long-an-issue-with-oracle/3392848#3392848) on a question on SO says

> ... you can read a LONG from a remote database, but you can't read a CLOB

I did not find anything about this on the internet, is it true? Any documentation or citings for this will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is correct in a certain context, for simple select statements over a DB link, you'll get this error:

> **ORA-22992**: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables.

From the errors manual:

> **Cause**: A remote LOB column cannot be referenced.
>   **Action**: Remove references to LOBs in remote tables.

I also had trouble finding definitive documentation on this...but we just ran into the same issue in our data warehouse.  However, there are several work-arounds available, [pulling the data over or creating a view](http://jiri.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/query-clob-across-db-link-with-in-simple-view/) for example.

Answer (score 3):

@Peter Ilfrich: Doesn't that throw an exception when trying to access any clobs over 4000 bytes?

This is a little more convaluted, but it means you can safely pull back small clobs (< 4000) over a dblink.

```
select dbms_lob.substr@<link>((select <columnName> from dual@<link>), 4000, 1)  
  from <table>@<link>  
 where dbms_lob.getlength@<link>((select <columnName> from dual@<link>)) <= 4000;
```

---

Reading a CLOB (or a BLOB) over a dblink **is possible** with this PL/SQL package:
 https://github.com/HowdPrescott/Lob_Over_DBLink

Comment: This worked for me when all of the other methods failed. Thank you.

Comment: Correction: I was able to query the table using the above package but the CLOB column is null.

Comment: And finally -- the above code did work for getting the first 4,000 characters.

Comment: This works for me too, and was able to pull more than 4000 by substring next chunks:     `select dbms_lob.substr@<link>(<columnName>, 4000, 1) chunk_1, dbms_lob.substr@<link>(<columnName>, 4000, 4001) chunk_2, dbms_lob.substr@<link>(<columnName>, 4000, 8001) chunk_3, ...<etc as needed>... 
  from <table>@<link> `

Answer (score 2):

**If** both DB schemes are in the same Oracle instance, you can use the following workaround:

`select (select <columnName> from dual) <columnName> from <table>@<link>`

This will return you the same as if you would access a local LOB column.

Comment: for some strange reason, it doesn't work in a view, but lead to a solution in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Which is what? Here's some filler text for my question.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 12.2 finally added support for [distributed LOBs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adlob/distributed-LOBs.html#GUID-7E450E86-3E4E-4714-A164-FD36B93722F6).  We can now read data types like CLOB and XMLType over database links without any workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble yesterday. This is My solution: create a romote  view on the romote table, when comes the CLOB cols, use to_char(),such as to_char(col2). Then you can select data from the view. It may not be a good solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Materialized View from remote table and then use from that for your needs

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:LG2eG1gThV8J:https://community.oracle.com/thread/471047%3Fstart%3D0%26tstart%3D0+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ir

Answer (score 0):

When your table from dblink it's an Oracle Big Data External table (in my case an external table over a Hive table), you need to create a materialized view over it and use that materialized view with the above mentioned pl/sql package: https://github.com/HowdPrescott/Lob_Over_DBLink

Works for clobs > 4000.

Tested only for CLOB!