# OracleCommand doesn't pick up LONG data types on ExecuteReader

Tags: .net, plsql, oracle11g, varchar2

I have a select query which retrieves a LONG data type value. SQL Developer execution pulls the data but the `OracleCommand` doesn't retrieve the value. Instead it returns empty strings even though I know that the values exist in the database.

Is there a way to convert LONG type into VARCHAR2? The values stored in that field are plain text? Also I'm only doing a `SELECT` on the table.

```
SELECT REQ_COL FROM TEST_TABLE
```

I've tried `TO_CHAR` but that didn't work.

NOTE: This is a vendor database that I have no control over changing the data types of columns. I am only reading the data from the database.

Comment: What is `OracleCommand` ?

Comment: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=430

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: LONG or CLOB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599211/oracle-long-or-clob)

Comment: I googled "OracleCommand" and "ExecuteReader" and apparently they are part of the [Microsoft .Net framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab4kxd8h(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Actually a duplicate of this (that has a more complete answer): [C# - How to get oracle long raw type value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644572/c-sharp-how-to-get-oracle-long-raw-type-value)

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this same problem while querying SYS.DBA_TRIGGERS.  I have found that setting cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = -1 solves it.